# Mobile application architecture vs others application architecture

Tags: mobile, architecture

I'm new to mobile development world so i want to know what's the difference between mobile application **architecture** and other simple application architecture (no mobile application).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile applications are similar to Rich Client architecture in all significant ways.